# How to convert callback code into promise format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, angular-promise

I am manually successfully able to telnet to `linux345` at port `2345`.
This means the following code should display output as `0`

However, the code output is returning `1`.
It seems that converting the `callback` to `async promise` format will help resolve the issue.
Please suggest how the updated code would look like.

```
const net = require('net');

const HOST = 'linux345';
const PORT = 2345;
let ErrCode = 1;

const client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    ErrCode = 0;
});

client.on('data', function(data) {    
    console.log('Client received: ' + data);
     if (data.toString().endsWith('exit')) {
       client.destroy();
    }
});

client.on('close', function() {
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
    ErrCode = err.code;
    console.log(ErrCode);
});

console.log(ErrCode);
```

Comment: Or... you could just move the last `console.log()` into one of the callback functions where it makes sense

Comment: I need to utilize value of `ErrCode` at other places in the code. So, would probably need to convert it to `async promise` format

Comment: Convert _what_, exactly? You have four asynchronous event handlers, one of which (_data_) fires continuously. What is it you think that _"converting the `callback` to `async promise` format"_ is going to do here?

Comment: The only pattern I can see working for you here is an [async generator](https://javascript.info/async-iterators-generators#async-generators) wrapping the `data` event callback

Answer (score 0):

```
let ErrCode = 1;

const client = new net.Socket();

const connect = util.promisify(client.connect);

async function testFun() {
    try {
        let data = await connect(PORT, HOST);
        ErrCode = 0;
        console.log('Client received: ' + data);
        if (data.toString().endsWith('exit')) {
            client.destroy();
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {
        ErrCode = -1;
    }
}

testFun().then(() => {
    console.log(ErrCode)
}
)
```

uses [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

> Takes a function following the common error-first callback style, i.e.
>   taking a (err, value) => ... callback as the last argument, and
>   returns a version that returns promises.

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar. I am not able to under error-first callback style. Can you please provide updated code?

Comment: @meallhour which call do you want to convert to promise?

Comment: I need help to get correct value of `ErrCode` which is `0` at the end.

Comment: @meallhour check my updated answer and comment if you face any issues

Comment: I am getting `-1` as output even when it is successfully having a telnet connection.

Comment: @meallhour u might have gotten some error add console.log(err) within catch block and check

Comment: getting exception `TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
    at Socket.connect (net.js:901:12)
    at Promise (internal/util.js:274:30)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at internal/util.js:273:12`